# Infer SWIFT/BIC code from IBAN?

Tags: banking, international-transfer, iban, swift

Is it possible to infer / deduct [SWIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362) code from [IBAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) code, if yes how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. They are totally different. In UK part of the BIC is part of IBAN. But other countries it is totally different.

Comment: the country code is however consistent accross the two (iban and bic)